# How to open an excel file explicitly using Robot Framework in Windows

Tags: robotframework

I need to open an Excel file explicitly to perform further operations using white library.

I tried this in Windows OS. I tried to open the excel file using ExcelLibrary-Open Excel keyword and also Run keyword of Operating System Library. But in both cases, system is not opening file explicitly.

Approach 1 - Using Open Excel keyword of Excel Library

```
*** Settings ***
Library    WhiteLibrary
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    ExcelLibrary        

*** Test Cases ***
Open Excel and perform Operation  
    Open Excel    D:/Regression_Suite/Test_Cases.xls    True
    Sleep    10s
```

Approach 2 - Using Run keyword of Operating System

```
*** Settings ***
Library    WhiteLibrary
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    ExcelLibrary        

*** Test Cases ***
Open Excel and perform Operation 
    Run    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office15/EXCEL.EXE ${EXECDIR}${/}Test_Cases.xls
    Sleep    10s
```

I expect the Excel file to opened explicitly, so that I can perform further operations using WhiteLibrary

Answer (score 3):

Use python's [`os.startfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) call - this will open the file with the associated program, the same as double clicking is in Explorer:

```
Evaluate    os.startfile("${EXECDIR}${/}Test_Cases.xls")
```

The call is going to return control to your next code line immediately, so you have to wait a bit for Excel to actually start before interacting with it.